# Portion of Image as Background

Tags: html, css

I have a sprite sheet with several images in there.

I'd like to display one of these images (inside the sprite sheet somewhere) as the background of my `div` element. However, I want to have some space around the sprite, so it has to be clipped from the sprite sheet somehow.

I'd like a solution that ideally only uses CSS.

Comment: show us the sprite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming having padding in the div is ok, you can use `background-clip: content-box`.  Then, add padding to the div equal to the amount of spacing you want.  The background-clip will prevent the background image from showing up in the padding space.

Below is an example:

```css
.sprite {
  background-image: url('https://www.vg-resource.com/attachment.php?aid=7093');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -12px -140px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite"></div>
```

Note that you will need to account for the padding in the calculation for determining where the sprite is.  In my example, the sprite is actually at (32, 160), but I needed to subtract (20, 20) for the padding.